# Spring Beans: DriverManagerDataSource converting to sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have a Spring MVC project that I am using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to connect to a `postgres database`.

When I try to launch my application, I get an exception:

```
Cannot convert value of type 
[org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] 
to required type [sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource] for 
property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

My `dataSource` bean looks like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/********" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="********" />
</bean>
```

I have connected to postgres with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` before. Am I missing a dependency that makes this conversion possible, or what is the problem?

Comment: i suspect some jar issue in your classpath, could you please check once.

Comment: I have: postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar and spring-jdbc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar in my classpath as the two that look relevant. Are there more that I need?

Comment: May be you have wrong import wherever you are using `DataSource` class make sure it is imported from `javax.sql.DataSource`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception itsel reveals that it is expecting `sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource`

and found `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`

That implies you have wrong import wherever you are using `DataSource` class make sure it is imported from `javax.sql.DataSource`